# How can I launch the sub applets in the GNOME's Control Center (v3) directly from the command line?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Is there a trick to launching these applets via the command line directly vs. having to launch the GNOME Control Center (aka. Settings) and then navigating to them through the UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the applets under GNOME Control Center by appending their names to the command:

```
$ gnome-control-center <applet name>
```

#### Examples

Launching the sound applet?

```
$ gnome-control-center sound
```

[image: ss #1]

Launching the printers applet?

[image: ss #2]

What are all the names of these applets?

```
$ gnome-control-center -l
Available panels:
    background
    bluetooth
    color
    datetime
    display
    info
    keyboard
    mouse
    network
    notifications
    online-accounts
    power
    printers
    privacy
    region
    search
    sharing
    sound
    universal-access
    user-accounts
    wacom
```