# GNOME System Monitor "System" tab

Tags: gnome

In an earlier version of GNOME System Monitor on lubuntu there was an addition tab, "System" which displayed some handy system information in a single location including Ubuntu version, Linux kernel version, amount of RAM and processor info.

How is this available now? Since the info was there in a previous version it seems like the complete removal of the tab would have been replaced by some other method of providing the same functionality. This is useful by providing GUI users a simple way to report basic info about their system to support people.

[image: Screen shot of System tab of Gnome System Monitor in Ubuntu 12.04.]

**NOTE:** The above is from an [htorque ask ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/12497/10709).

Answer (score 2):

It's likely not available as a extension to that GUI. There are however several alternative tools that will give you the same/similar info both GUI and command line, such as: SysInfo, `lshw`, `hwinfo`, etc.

If you want a truly GNOME experience then the system settings under the GNOME Control Center (`gnome-control-center`) have all that info in a single dialog. Its called Settings.

You can get at it directly via the command line like so:

```
$ gnome-control-center info
```

*Fedora*

[image: ss#1]

*Ubuntu*

[image: ss#2]

#### My GUI's missing icons on *buntu?

If you find you're "System Settings" icon is missing, then you system is likely missing this particular package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

#### References

- [How can I launch the sub applets in the GNOME's Control Center (v3) directly from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131929/how-can-i-launch-the-sub-applets-in-the-gnomes-control-center-v3-directly-fro)
- [System Settings icons missing in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466720/system-settings-icons-missing-in-14-04)

Comment: "sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center; gnome-control-center" produces a window with just three sections with headings/labeled icon: Personal/Language Support, Hardware/Printers and System/Software & Updates with a menu Application>(Help, Quit)

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII - What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Let me click on the System tab of GNOME System Monitor and tell you...14.04.1 LTS

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII - it doesn't look like mine?

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII - Are you running just a vanilla Ubuntu or is this some other *buntu? My screenshot is from a vanilla 14.04 system.

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII - 32 or 64? Not that it should matter but I'm about to download Lubuntu just to help you out 8-)

Comment: Linux road 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: What if you install this package? `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, and re-run the above?